# Get float from class in a SerializedProperty

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to start using sciptable objects as describe in **[this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raQ3iHhE_Kk)**. Here is my code:

Here is my FloatVariable:

```
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu]
public class FloatVariable : ScriptableObject
{
    public float value;
}
```

Here is my FloatReference:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

[Serializable]
public class FloatReference
{
    public bool use_constant = true;
    public float constant_value;
    public FloatVariable variable_value;

    public float v
    {
        get
        {
            return use_constant ? constant_value : variable_value.value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (use_constant) throw new Exception("Cannot assign constant_value");
            else variable_value.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my GameplayManager where I have one `FloatReference` value:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEditor;
using System;


public class GameplayManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FloatReference pl_orb_mode;
}
```

Here is my `GameplayManagerEditor` where I try to get `float` from `FloatVariable` class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System;

[CustomEditor(typeof(GameplayManager))]
public class GameplayManagerEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        SerializedProperty pl_orb_mode = serializedObject.FindProperty("pl_orb_mode");
        SerializedProperty variable = pl_orb_mode.FindPropertyRelative("variable_value");
        SerializedProperty the_value = variable.FindPropertyRelative("value");

        float test = the_value.floatValue;
        Debug.Log(test);
    }

}
```

When I try to get my `float test = the_value.floatValue;` I get an error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
GameplayManagerEditor.OnInspectorGUI () (at Assets/Shared/Scripts/Editor/GameplayManagerEditor.cs:18)
```

So I can get the `FloatVariable variable` class as a `SerializedProperty` but I can't get its `value` property. **Why is that so and how to make it work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because FloatVariable is inherit from ScriptableObject, so variable_value becomes a reference not a property in SerializedObject.

You have 2 choice.

Don't use ScriptableObject:

```
[Serializable]
public class FloatVariable
{
    public float value;
}
```

Or edit the reference object:

```
var so = new SerializedObject(((GameplayManager)target).pl_orb_mode.variable_value);
var the_value = so.FindPropertyRelative("value");
...
so.ApplyModifiedProperties();
```

Notice that the second way since FloatVariable is a reference object, change on it will change all other objects that refer to it.

Comment: Are you talking about [this property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)? Or by saying property you mean a [member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/members)? And what are reference [members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/members) in c#? I have not heard about them.

Comment: Also, I am trying to implement it like that: `var so = new SerializedObject(((FloatReference)pl_orb_mode).variable_value);` and it does not work.

Comment: It's not about c#, it's unity serialization work. I said `property` means `SerializedProperty`.

Comment: I have a mistake in my answer and now I have fixed it, please check again.